# Power of a sum in a factor ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $n\in$ $\mathbb N$. Find a closed formula for $$(c_1x+c_2y+c_3z)^n$$ in the factor ring $\mathbb Z[x,y,z] / \langle x^2,y^2,z^2\rangle$.

What exactly does it mean to find a closed formula? From my understanding, we have $x^2$, $y^2$, $z^2$ equivalent to $0$, so $$(c_1x+x_2y+c_3z)^2 = c_1^2x^2+c_2^2y^2+c_3^2z^2+2c_1c_2xy+2c_1c_3xz+2c_2c_3yz$$ $$= 2c_1c_2xy+2c_1c_3xz+2c_2c_3yz$$
Then, $$(c_1x+c_2y+c_3z)^3 = (c_1x+c_2y+c_3z)(2c_1c_2xy+2c_1c_3xz+2c_2c_3yz)$$ $$=2c_1c_2c_3xyz+2c_1c_2c_3xyz+2c_1c_2c_3xyz$$ $$= 6c_1c_2c_3xyz$$
Continuing in this way, will the sum always be $0$ for $n>3$?  How do I find a formula for this?

Comment: Yes, it will be of the form $a_1x+a_2y+a_3z + a_4xy + a_5xz+a_6yz + a_7xyz$. So you need to figure out what$a_1,\dots, a_7$ are, in terms of $n$.

Comment: And yes, it is $0$ for all $n>3$. I think giving the values for $n=1,2,3$ and noting that it is $0$ for $n>3$ is 'closed form,' but 'closed form' has no agreed-upon definition.

Comment: I changed $\mathbb Z[x,y,z] / <x^2,y^2,z^2>$ to $\mathbb Z[x,y,z] / \langle x^2,y^2,z^2\rangle$.  That is standard. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x^iy^jz^k$ with $i+j+k=n$, and $n\ge 4$. Then at least one of the $i,j,k$ is $\ge 2$ (otherwise $i+j+k\le3$). Since in your ring $x^2=y^2=z^2=0$ you get $x^iy^jz^k=0$. Thus $(c_1x+c_2y+c_3z)^n=0$ for $n\ge4$.